# Синоним client-server -> клиент-сервер

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Меткой [client-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-server) помечено 50 вопросов, меткой [клиент-сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80) помечено 107 вопросов.
Предлагаю оставить русскую метку [клиент-сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80), а [client-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-server) сделать синонимом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синонимизация меток проведена.